# How to change css property in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to change css width property of my element on some condition

```
<div className="consoleLayoutRoot-sideMenu">
        <ConsoleSideMenu />
 </div>
```

css

```
.consoleLayoutRoot-sideMenu .ant-menu {
  padding-top: 30px;
 
  /* background-color: #191146 !important; */
}
```

I am doing this way..but nothing is happening

```
document.getElementsByClassName("conjnjnot-sideMenjnjbhbhu.annjn ").style.width = "77px";
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Create your state variable

   ```js
   const [pickColor, setPickColor] = useState("#000000");
   ```
2. Use style

   ```
   const myComponent = () =>{ 
     const [pickColor, setPickColor] = useState("#000000");
     return (
       <div>
         style={{backgroundColor: pickColor}}
       </div>
     );
   };
   ```

When you update the state of `pickColor` it will change the color of the `div` element.

Answer (score 1):

That's not working because [you're treating a list as though it were an element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method). But it's also fundamentally not how you would do this in a React project.

Instead, you'd have the component re-render when the condition becomes true (perhaps by setting a state member). When rendering the `div`, you optionally include a `style` or a class name depending on whether you want the width applied:

```
<div className={`consoleLayoutRoot-sideMenu ${shouldHaveWidthClass ? "width-class" : ""}`}>
        <ConsoleSideMenu />
</div>
```

...where `.width-class { width: 50px; }` is in your stylesheet.

Or with inline style, but inline styles are best avoided:

```
<div className="consoleLayoutRoot-sideMenu" style={shouldHaveWidthSetting ? { width: "50px" } : undefined}>
        <ConsoleSideMenu />
</div>
```

Here's an example (using a class);

```js
const {useState} = React;

const ConsoleSideMenu = () => <span>x</span>;

const Example = () => {
    const [includeWidth, setIncludeWidth] = useState(false);
    
    const toggle = ({currentTarget: { checked }}) => {
        setIncludeWidth(checked);
    };
    
    return <React.Fragment>
        <div className={`consoleLayoutRoot-sideMenu ${includeWidth ? "width-class" : ""}`}>
                <ConsoleSideMenu />
        </div>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" onChange={toggle} checked={includeWidth} />
            Include width class
        </label>
    </React.Fragment>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.width-class {
    width: 50px;
}
.consoleLayoutRoot-sideMenu {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: Or with an array : `<div className={['classes classes', condition ? 'classes' : ''].join(' ').trim()>...</div>`. `trim()` isn't mandatory, it just prevent the empty space in case the condition is false.

Comment: @QuentinGrisel - Sure, lots of ways to skin this cat. (I've been known to use a helper function for it: `className={classes("always", "also-always", maybe && "sometimes")}` that builds a string from string argument values [ignoring non-strings like `false` and `undefined`].)